# Odoo 12 encoding latin1 unable to resolve

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, encoding, odoo, phppgadmin

I have installed Odoo12 on Ubuntu 18.04 using installation script [Odoo Install](https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript)
The server started successfully and when trying to create the first database, the error below showed up.

> Database creation error: encoding "UTF8" does not match locale "en_US" DETAIL: The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "LATIN1".

then I have run the below script which has solved the problem before on odoo 10.
it was run from **postgres** user

```
psql postgres -c "update pg_database set datallowconn = TRUE where datname = 'template0';"
psql template0 -c "update pg_database set datistemplate = FALSE where datname = 'template1';"
psql template0 -c "drop database template1;"
psql template0 -c "create database template1 with ENCODING = 'UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.utf8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.utf8' template = template0;"
psql template0 -c "update pg_database set datistemplate = TRUE where datname = 'template1';"
psql template1 -c "update pg_database set datallowconn = FALSE where datname = 'template0';"
```

As the problem persisted I installed phpPgAdmin and noticed that the Encoding is still "Latin1" ; So I droped the database and created a new one manually from the phppgAdmin interface using same name and same owner.
below is a shot from the phpPgAdmin
[phpPgAdmin shot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLkEL.png)

Still the same problem unresolved and the error is shown as seen below.
[Odoo Encoding Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABVXB.png)

Noting that this is the return of calling "locale" on my server.
[locale status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7nCh.png)

Comment: I have also tried to add "db_template = template0" in /etc/odoo-server.conf and restarted the postgresql and odoo services and still the problem unsolved.

Comment: I have managed to solve my own problem by Re-installing Ubuntu and passing 
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
and choosing en_US.UTF-8 as my default before installing odoo (and before PostgreSQL as well)
But I hope that someone can answer my question as a benefit for the community

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure locale before postgres installation.

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

or you can reinint db

```
initdb --pgdata=/path/to/postgresql -E utf8
```